# Exporting layer to GeoJSON the result is in the wrong coordinate system

Tags: qgis, geojson, export

I have a layer with `MultiLineStringZM` features that was imported in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.
This I want to export to geojson in EPSG 25832 (UTM).

However even if I specify EPSG:25832 in the export it still comes out in EPSG:4326.
It doesn't help if I export the layer to a new shape-file layer with EPSG:25832 coordinate system.
I can check in python console and when I show the content of the geometry the coordinates are correct (in EPSG:25832) but when I try to export the new layer that is in EPSG:25832 to GeoJSON it still comes out in EPSG:4326.
Does anyone know how to solve this???

(QGIS 3.14)

Comment: It seems you are using PyQGIS console?! You mention you "try to export the new layer that is in EPSG:25832". How do you do it? Can you add your code and/or your screenshot if GUI? FYI, GeoJSON is not supposed to use projected coordinates (EPSG 25832) although it's possible but should always use EPSG:4326 (other EPSG codes supported in old GeoJSON specs, nowadays outdated support)

Comment: Bearing in mind that GeoJSON the official specification only has one CRS which is CRS:84 (like EPSG:4326 but with different axis order)...  but for backwards compatibility, the GDAL GeoJSON driver has a layer creation option to allow you to specify `RFC7946=NO` which should allow you to use any CRS

Comment: Thanks for the tip @mmtoken. In the Layer export dialog there is an option for setting RF to either yes or no with no being the default. However the tooltip says it is RFC 8142 that is set. In the documentation for GeoJSON (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html) it says that NO is the default... Choosing yes or no has no effect, the result is the same (long, lat)

Comment: I have not found a solution yet but I instead concatenate attributes->json and geom->json manually which works well.